# Parallel reading and union of delta tables (pyspark)

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I need to read many delta tables in azure object storage (block blobs) that share a common schema but not common paths.

Iterating over the paths with a for loop is performing very poorly because the list of paths is long and the operation can't be parallelized.

```
union_df = None
for path in paths:
  df = self.spark.read.load(deltapath)
  if union_df:
    union_df = union_df.unionByName(df)
  else:
    union_df = df
```

The final result should be a union of all delta tables read from a list of paths.

The issue is that I cannot pass directly a list of paths to spark.read.load, because this results in the exception:

```
Databricks Delta does not support multiple input paths in the load() API. To build a single DataFrame by loading multiple paths from the same Delta table, please load the root path of the Delta table with the corresponding partition filters. If the multiple paths are from different Delta tables, please use Dataset's union()/unionByName() APIs to combine the DataFrames generated by separate load() API calls.
```

Example paths:
`['wasbs://refined@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/ABC/1/', 'wasbs://refined@mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/ABC/2']`

Note that using the path until ..ABC/ is not going to work because no delta log is present at ..ABC/

Tldr: Tried the following approaches:

Loop over paths -> Slow performance

Read from root object -> No delta log at root exception

Use a generator function that yields df and then iterate over the generator to union -> marginal performance gain

Comment: Update: Following advice by Kashyap has helped. Using the databricks workflows orchestrator, the parallelism increased by having one task per group of paths to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your target table is a delta table, which supports ATOMIC transactions, you can run `N` x `spark.read.delta('src_table1..N').write.delta('target_table')` jobs in parallel.

Many ways of doing that, simplest I can think of is

- have 2 notebook jobs, worker and orchestrator
- orchestrator just triggers worker job ([using dbutils](https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#dbutilsnotebook-api), can also use [other APIs to trigger](https://databricks-sdk-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait.html) for finer control) with one table-name as param and
- worker reads data from that table and writes to target-table using simple append, can also [use merge instead](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#merge-examples&language-python).

##### Untested example:

Worker notebook:

```py
dbutils.widgets.text("delta_table_name", "", "delta_table_name goes here")
delta_table_name = dbutils.widgets.get("delta_table_name")

df_src = spark.read.delta('delta_table_name')

df_src.write.mode("append").saveAsTable.delta('target_table', append=True)

# or perhaps use merge?
# DeltaTable.forName('target_table').alias("t").merge(
#     df_src.alias("s"),
#     "t.uniqueId = s.uniqueId") \
#   .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
#   .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
#   .execute()
    

dbutils.notebook.exit(
    # here -- if you want to return some status back to orchestrator
)
```

Orchestrator notebook:

```py
list_src_delta_tables = ['table1', 'table2', ...]

for t in list_src_delta_tables:
    dbutils.notebook.run("worker_notebook", 0, {"delta_table_name": t})
```

---

This is assuming a batch mode. If you're looking to stream delta changes then instead of `spark.read()` to read from source table, you can

- [use Change Data Feed](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-change-data-feed.html) or
- [Spark structured streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#quick-example) or
- [DLT pipelines](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/index.html)

Comment: Hmm, this is a good work around. I am using databricks workflows to run the jobs so I'll try to create many parallel "extract" steps based on the same notebook, and have the next transform step depend on all of these so that it doesn't start until all are completed.

Answer (score 0):

Looping over the paths shouldn't be slow unless you're talking about millions of delta tables. In the code you show there's a bug. Your union_df = None is within the loop, resetting the union_df every time, instead of unioning.

Comment: Thanks indeed the union_df = None should not be in the loop and is not in my actual code. I edited this mistake out of the question. 

My understanding is that for loops are always executed sequentially only by one node (worker) on pyspark, so they are very slow, because the tables are quite large and each load takes significant time. I'm trying to find a way to make more workers read the tables in parallel.